# html файл не видит css документа ну или просто не читает его

Tags: html, css

[image: html code]

[image: css code]

Пробовал перекидывать из папки с русскими символами в папку без

Comment: так вы где-то прописали, чтобы он его подключал? или ждете что оно вдруг само сделается?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/sposoby-dobavleniya-stiley-na-stranitsu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно работать. Вы неправильно указали путь к файлу:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```